# How to manage memory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

I have a simple software that I developed with python. My computer is not very powerful, but I need to run 20 to 40 of these programs on my computer at the same time.

When I entered the task manager, I observed that although the program is very simple, it takes up a lot of memory. You can see it in the picture below;

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong with memory management? How can I configure the program to make my computer less tiring? Thank you for your help :)

My code is below;

```
import ops
import talib
import numpy
import math
import time
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import smtplib
import config
from binance.client import Client

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    now = datetime.now()

    if (now.minute % 5) == 0 and now.second == 3:
        ops.check_internet_conn(urllib, time)
        now = ops.check_time(datetime, time, now, 5)
        client = Client(config.api_key, config.api_secret)
        balance = 15.0
        is_active = ops.check_active_positions(client, time, "ETHUSDT")
        candles = ops.get_candlesticks(client, time)
        close_prices = ops.get_close_prices(candles)
        numpy_prices = numpy.array(close_prices)
        ema_200 = talib.EMA(numpy_prices, 200)
        selected_cs = 498
        ts = int(candles[selected_cs][0])
        dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000)

        high = float("{:.2f}".format(float(candles[(selected_cs - 1)][2])))
        low = float("{:.2f}".format(float(candles[(selected_cs - 1)][3])))
        close = float("{:.2f}".format(float(candles[selected_cs][4])))

        ema = float("{:.2f}".format(float(ema_200[selected_cs])))
        bb_upper = float("{:.2f}".format(float(upper[selected_cs])))
        bb_middle = float("{:.2f}".format(float(middle[selected_cs])))
        bb_lower = float("{:.2f}".format(float(lower[selected_cs])))

        if close > ema:
            direction = "BUY"
        else:
            direction = "SELL"

        stop_loss = ops.calc_stop_loss(direction, close, high, low)
        take_profit = ops.calc_take_profit(direction, close, high, low)
        leverage = 3

        quantity = ops.calc_quantity(time, balance, leverage, close)

        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("Run Time:             {0}:{1}:{2}".format(now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
        print("CS Datetime:         ", dt_obj)
        print("USDT Balance:        ", balance, "USDT")
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("High:                ", high)
        print("Low:                 ", low)
        print("Close:               ", close)
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("Ema                  ", ema)
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("Entry Price:         ", close)
        print("Take Profit:         ", take_profit)
        print("Stop Loss:           ", stop_loss)
        print("Leverage:            ", leverage)
        print("Direction:           ", direction)
        print("Quantity:            ", quantity)
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("Is Active:           ", is_active)
        print("----------------------------------------")

        b_cons = close > ema and is_active == False and 0 < leverage < 101
        s_cons = close < ema and is_active == False and 0 < leverage < 101

        if b_cons or s_cons:
            ops.close_open_orders(client, time, "ETHUSDT")
            ops.set_leverage(client, time, leverage)
            ops.place_order(client, time, direction, quantity, close)
            ops.set_stop_loss(client, time, direction, stop_loss)
            ops.set_take_profit(client, time, direction, take_profit)
```

ops.py

```
def check_internet_conn(urllib, time):

    print("\n----------------------------------------")
    while True:
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
            print("İnternet bağlantısı mevcut.")
            break
        except Exception:
            print("İnternet bağlantısı yok. Tekrar bağlantı deneniyor..")
            time.sleep(5)

def check_time(datetime, time, old_now, mn):
    now = datetime.now()
    if old_now.minute != now.minute:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

            now = datetime.now()

            if (now.minute % mn) == 0 and now.second == 0:
                break

    return now

def get_candlesticks(client, time):
    while True:
        try:
            candles = client.futures_klines(symbol='ETHUSDT', interval=client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE)

            if len(candles) > 0:
                return candles

        except Exception as e:
            print("Candles Error:", e)
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

def get_close_prices(cs_list):
    close_prices = []

    for candle in cs_list:
        close_prices.append(float(candle[4]))

    return close_prices

def calc_stop_loss(side, close_price, last_high, last_low):
    if side == "BUY":
        difference = close_price - last_low
        stop_loss = float("{:.2f}".format(close_price - (difference * 1.1)))
    else:
        difference = last_high - close_price
        stop_loss = float("{:.2f}".format(close_price + (difference * 1.1)))

    return stop_loss

def calc_take_profit(side, close_price, last_high, last_low):
    if side == "BUY":
        difference = close_price - last_low
        take_profit = float("{:.2f}".format(close_price + (difference * 1.1 * 1.5)))
    else:
        difference = last_high - close_price
        take_profit = float("{:.2f}".format(close_price - (difference * 1.1 * 1.5)))

    return take_profit

def calc_quantity(time, balance, leverage, close):
    while True:
        try:
            quantity = float("{:.3f}".format(((balance * 0.9) / close) * leverage))
            if type(quantity) == float:
                return quantity
        except Exception as e:
            print("Quantity Error:", e)
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

def check_active_positions(client, time, coin):
    while True:
        try:
            positions = client.futures_position_information()
            amount = None

            for pos in positions:
                if pos["symbol"] == coin:
                    amount = float(pos["positionAmt"])

            if len(positions) > 0 and amount == 0:
                return False
            elif len(positions) > 0 and amount != 0:
                return True
        except Exception as e:
            print("Check Active Position Error:", e)
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

def close_open_orders(client, time, symbol):
    while True:
        try:
            client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=symbol)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Close Open Orders Error:", e)
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

def set_leverage(client, time, leverage):
    while True:
        try:
            client.futures_change_leverage(symbol="ETHUSDT", leverage=leverage)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Set Leverage Error:", e)
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

def place_order(client, time, direction, quantity, close):
    if direction == "BUY":
        while True:
            try:
                buy_sell_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side=direction, type="LIMIT",
                                                             timeinforce="GTC", quantity=quantity, price=close)
                print("Buy Order :", buy_sell_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Buy Order Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                buy_sell_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side=direction, type="LIMIT",
                                                             timeinforce="GTC", quantity=quantity, price=close)
                print("Buy Order :", buy_sell_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Sell Order Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass

def set_stop_loss(client, time, direction, stop_loss):
    if direction == "BUY":
        while True:
            try:
                stop_loss_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side="SELL", type="STOP_MARKET",
                                                              stopPrice=stop_loss, closePosition="true")
                print("Stop Loss Order :", stop_loss_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Set Stop Loss Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                stop_loss_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side="BUY", type="STOP_MARKET",
                                                              stopPrice=stop_loss, closePosition="true")
                print("Stop Loss Order :", stop_loss_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break

            except Exception as e:
                print("Set Stop Loss Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass

def set_take_profit(client, time, direction, take_profit):
    if direction == "BUY":
        while True:
            try:
                take_profit_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side="SELL",
                                                                type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", stopPrice=take_profit,
                                                                closePosition="true")
                print("Take Profit Order:", take_profit_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Set Take Profit Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                take_profit_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol="ETHUSDT", side="BUY",
                                                                type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", stopPrice=take_profit,
                                                                closePosition="true")
                print("Take Profit Order:", take_profit_order)
                print("----------------------------------------")
                break

            except Exception as e:
                print("Set Take Profit Error:", e)
                time.sleep(1)
                pass
```

Comment: The memory that PyCharm uses isn't related to running your script. It's a very complex program with many features, and it uses lots of memory for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On posted printscreen you have shown [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). To be clear, PyCharm is not your python programme. You should run you python code in console. In this case 20 consoles ([cmd](https://pythonbasics.org/execute-python-scripts/)). Moreover, PyCharm sometimes needs a lot of RAM and its completely normal.

If you have Windows OS you can try to run python code in cmd. Just type inside cmd window:

```
python [my_code].py
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about your memory usage, try running them on cmd if PyCharm is taking a lot of memory. Since it's an IDE, it might be doing several things in the background besides running your code.

Besides that, it might be worth profiling your python code for memory usage and see if you can do some kind of code optimizations. You can use something like [memory_profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) .